# PHP how to concat three strings separated by line break

Tags: php

I use:

```
$json_row["label"] = $recResult['year'] .' | '. $recResult['Titles']." | Dir.by.: " . $recResult['person'];
```

it returns :

```
2021 | Dune | Dir. by: Denis Villeneuve
```

what I need is to replace ' | ' with line break like

```
 2021 Dune 
 Dir. by: Denis Villeneuve
```

Is that possible?
The complete used code is

```
    <?php
require_once ' ';
$keyword = trim($_REQUEST['term']); 
$sugg_json = array(); 
$json_row = array(); 
$keyword = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $keyword); // replace multiple spaces from the input
$query = 'SELECT * from titlessearch WHERE yeartitle LIKE :term order by year desc' ; 
$stmt = $DBcon->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute(array(':term'=>"%$keyword%"));
if ( $stmt->rowCount()>0 ) {
    while($recResult = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $json_row["id"] = $recResult['posturl'];
    $json_row["value"] = $recResult['Titles'];  
    $json_row["label"] = $recResult['yeartitle'] .' | '. $recResult['Titles'] ." | Dir. By.: " . $recResult['person'] ;
    array_push($sugg_json, $json_row);
    }
} else {
    $json_row["id"] = "#";
    $json_row["value"] = "";
    $json_row["label"] = "Some Greek text here";
    array_push($sugg_json, $json_row);
}
$jsonOutput = json_encode($sugg_json, SON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    print $jsonOutput;
```

Any of suggestions I tried looks like HTML is not interpreted

Comment: That's not JSON, that's a PHP array, and you're doing PHP string concatenation. Test question: How do you create a newline in PHP?

Comment: are you rendering it in your PHP or sending it as a response??

Comment: What is line break you mean? `\n` or `<br>`?

Comment: It's a responce of an Autocomplete Search Box / textbox... It returns string in one line and I need to separate it in two lines. Tried \\n but it doen't work

Comment: There is no such thing in html. so what is an Autocomplete Search Box / textbox?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like that? str_replace function is makes a good job.

```php
<?php
$recResult['year'] = 2022;
$recResult['Titles'] = "Prof. ";
$recResult['person'] = "James";
$json_row["label"] = $recResult['year'] .' | '. $recResult['Titles']." | Dir.by.: " . $recResult['person'];

echo str_replace ("|", "<br/>", $json_row["label"]);
```

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: @KostasKonstantinidis Can you explain what exactly doesn't work, please? Some error message.

Comment: No error messages. Ιt continues to display $json_row["label"]  as in its original form without replacing " | " with <br> or "\n"

Answer (score 0):

If you esc html then

```
$json_row["label"] = $recResult['year'] .' <br> '. $recResult['Titles']." <br /> Dir.by.: " . $recResult['person'];
```

or use `sprintf` function.

Comment: It just prints <br> and <br /> as text strings

Comment: it means that HTML is not interpreted. Can you show render function? Or it's API? or what?

Comment: I updated my question sharing the overall code

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing something like this, and the function implode allows you to concatenate the array values with a glue you specify (new line in this case)

```
$data = [
$recResult['year'],
$recResult['Titles'],
"Dir.by.: " . $recResult['person']
];

json_row["label"] = implode(PHP_EOL, $data);
```